# Searching within lists in Pandas dataframe Column, Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Situation**
I'm running into this issue working with a database with over 1,000 tables. I want to filter down the table names based on column name values. I'm trying to run a `str.contains()` on my dataframe, but get an error. Error reads `"None of [Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"` I was able to reproduce the error with dummy data.

**My goal is to return a dataframe filtered to 'table5' because it contains the column name 'date'**

```
listoftables = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'table5']
columnnames = [['age', 'name', 'school'], 
               ['age', 'name', 'school'], 
               ['age', 'name', 'school'], 
               ['age', 'name', 'school'], 
               ['audit', 'auditrunlist', 'date']]


example = pd.DataFrame(
    {'TableName': listoftables,
     'col_names'  : columnnames
    })

example[(example['col_names'].str.contains('date'))]
```

I *think* the error is because I'm searching for a string within a list. What confuses me more, if I run `example[(example['col_names'].str.contains('[audit, auditrunlist, date]'))]` I get the same error.

If I add one more column that isn't a **list**, I get the results I expect

```
listoftables = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'table5']
columnnames = [['age', 'name', 'school'], 
               ['age', 'name', 'school'], 
               ['age', 'name', 'school'], 
               ['age', 'name', 'school'], 
               ['audit', 'auditrunlist', 'date']]

no_list_columnnames = ['age, name, school', 
               'age name school', 
                'age name school', 
               'age name school', 
               'audit auditrunlist date']


example = pd.DataFrame(
    {'TableName': listoftables,
     'col_names'  : columnnames,
     'no_list_col_names' : no_list_columnnames
    })

# this returns what i expect
example[(example['no_list_col_names'].str.contains('date'))]
```

I think I have two outcomes, I can either try and find a way to search within a list in a pandas dataframe or I can find a way to convert a column in a pandas dataframe from a list to a string.

What is the better way to filter a pandas dataframe with a list as a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for pointing out this issue it is interesting,

my approach would be to use the classic **apply** to create a flag

```
df['flag']=df.apply(lambda x: 1 if 'date' in x['col_names'] else 0, axis=1)
```

after i would filter:

```
df_filtered=df.loc[df['flag']==1,:]
```

probably they exist clever options but this do the work

Comment: Easy to understand two step process. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in multiple ways.

-- Filter

```
example = example[[True if ('date' in i) else False for i in example['col_names']]]
```

-- Expanding the lists and then filter. The code will look nicer but might need more space.

```
example = example.explode('col_names')
example = example[example['col_names'] == 'date']
```

Comment: Thank you, `explode` is new to me and I'm sure I'll find a use case for it. My dataset is too large for it to work. The filter step is a one-liner, but @giulio's solution is easier to read.